# Hello, I set up a hook on nestJS using MongooseModule, but I'm having trouble injecting third-party services

Tags: mongoose, nestjs, hook

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Commande, CommandeSchema } from 'src/commande/commande.model';

@Module({
    imports: [
        MongooseModule.forFeatureAsync([
            {
                name: 'Commande',
                imports: [SharedModule],
                inject: [MyService],
                useFactory: async (myService: MyService) => {
                    const schema = CommandeSchema;
                    schema.post('save', async function (doc) {
                        const commande = doc as unknown as Commande;
                        await myService.savingLivraison(commande);
                    });
                    return schema;
                },
            },
        ]),],
    providers: [MyService],
    exports: [MyService]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

when I do that the SharedModule module does not load while I load it well in the AppModule and when I remove the exports line in the shared module I have the error: `[Nest] 25850  - 08/06/2023 17:02:52   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the CommandeModel (DatabaseConnection, ?, MyService).

what I want is to be able to use the myService in the context of MongooseModule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've created a circular dependency of the `SharedModule` on itself. The `SharedModule` needs to import the `MongooseModule`, but the `MongooseModule` needs to import the `SharedModule`. What you need to do is move the `MyService` to a module outside of the `SharedModule` which can then be imported by the `SharedModule` and the `MongooseModule`, and then the `SharedModule` can re-export this new module to make the `MyService` available anywhere the`SharedModule` is imported